# How to import a texture to be used as occlusion map?

Tags: unity, textures, import, lightmap, ambient-occlusion

The same way normal maps need to be imported as "Normal map" in the import settings, how should I setup an Ambient Occlusion texture to correctly work?

I've been searching around in the manual and the web but still not sure if AO maps should be imported as Lightmaps.

[image: texture import settings list]

Comment: Have you found any unwanted behaviour when leaving them as "Default"?